# What is the use of setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled()?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I was confused to what the purpose of adding a `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled` in the constructor of class that extends a `JPanel` and implements `KeyListener`.

What is the use of `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled()`?

Answer (score 0):

`setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled()` decides whether or not focus traversal keys (TAB key, SHIFT+TAB, etc.) are allowed to be used when the current `Component` has focus. For example:

```
JTextField tabAllowed = new JTextField();
JTextField tabNotAllowed = new JTextField();

tabAllowed.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true); // The default value is true.
tabNotAllowed.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); // The default value is overridden.
```

If the focus is on `tabAllowed`, then you can use the TAB key to go to the next `Component`. If the focus is on `tabNotAllowed`, then pressing the TAB key will not allow you to go to the next `Component`.

In your case, it might not be as useful since you are implementing `KeyListener`. If you want to set it as `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);` in your constructor, then you might want to use the following to gain focus assuming you have implemented traversal keys using the `KeyListener`:

```
setFocusable(true);
setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
// some code here
// ...
panel.grabFocus();
```